Is it possible to play with a friend on a starter account from the other faction?
I can see them but it doesn't look like I can invite them or add them as a friend. Starter Accounts also don't seem to be able to add someone with real id. It's weird because you can normally invite and play with people from the opposite faction.

I believe that you'll need to subscribe, to be able to play with your friend. According to Blizzard Support:

On the Starter Edition you will not have access to:

Most recent expansion content (quests, zones, allied characters, etc)
Characters above level 20
Pet Battles
Other chat channels and whispers to non-friends
All guild-related functions
Value added services (character transfers, faction changes, etc)
Party formation
Trade, mail, or the Auction House
Real ID
World of Warcraft voice chat. You can use Battle.net voice chat instead
The Emote function in text chat


(emphasis mine)

Blizzard is not completely right about their own game. You are able to form a party with a starter account. It just looks you are not able to do it with the other faction. I was forced to make a character on the same faction. Just if someone else wants to know.
The rest of this list seems to be true.
